# Is there a way to call a member function in init list?

Tags: c++, c++11, syntax, constructor, initialization

Is there a way to call a function in init list with no context of data memeber?

For example this:

```
class x{
public:
    x(char ch): ..., foo() {} // doesn't work
...
    void foo(); //foo sets the keys in keys[], different keys for different ch
private:
    char keys[10];
}
```

instead of this:

```
class x{
public:
    x(char ch): ...  {(ch == 'a') ? foo("asdfg..."): foo("qwert..") ;}
...
    void foo(); 
private:
    char keys[10];
}
```

Does the init list syntax always have to be {data member name}(value)?

Also, I read that it's preferable to use init list instead of the constructor's function because this way it doesn't make a copy, but in this case does it matter?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? If you're constructing data members then you should put their values in the ctor-initialiser, but don't try and throw every single thing from your constructor in there.

Comment: @Simple I've added some more code to clarify why. So you're saying I shouldn't bother with putting everything in the init list?

Comment: I wouldn't put `foo()` in the initialiser list if that's what it did. Unless you can move the code of `foo()` into `keys{values, in, here}`.

Comment: Put member initializations there, but not ordinary functions that you simply want to call from your constructor.

Comment: The initialisation list is used for initialisation. A function can't initialise any members - it can only assign values to them - so allowing one in the list wouldn't make any sense. (It's possible to use the *return value* of a function call to initialise a member, of course.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to call a member function in init list?

Yes.

But the result of an expression in the member initialization list must always be assigned to a member variable, so calling a `void` function in the member initialization list is going to need some hackery. It's possible but pointless, because the call could be just as well done in the constructor body.

What would make more sense in a member initialization list, is to call a function that returns a value that would be copied to the member. You cannot return raw arrays though, so that's not an opion unless you change the type of `keys`.

> Also, I read that it's preferable to use init list instead of the constructor's function because this way it doesn't make a copy, but in this case does it matter?

It's true that copy-initializing a member in the member initialization list allows the copy to be elided while copy-assigning in the constructor body does not. That includes copying the return value of a function that's called in the member initialization list, but it does not apply to any copy-assignments done inside the function. You've misunderstood how the use of member initialization list can avoid copying.

---

Now, default initializing and copying an array 10 characters is not a lot of work. But you can minimize the amount of copying by using aggregate initialization. For that, `x` would have to be an aggregate. There is already an aggregate that wraps an array in the standard library since c++11: `std::array`. I recommend that you use that instead of `x`. You can write a function that returns the desired array based on the parameter.

Comment: With `std::array`s I can "pour" the content of one char array into the data member char array just like assigning `int` to `int`?

Comment: @kuhaku sure, `std::array` is copyable.